# How should I start with SonarLint for C# Projects

Tags: sonarlint-vs

I am learning SonarLint plugin but finding very difficult and not able to understand how it works.
I have installed SonarLint for VS2015 Community Edition and then as per instructions i was trying to bind any random project from Team Connect. But then I am not able to see those fancy block which will tell me something like "Null reference exception will occur.."

Please guide me what are the steps need to perform while working with SonarLint for C# projects to perform code analysis.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

SonarLint gets installed outside of any particular project. You install the extension either through VS Extensions or by downloading it from here - https://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/index.html. Once it's installed, restart VS and you should be good to go. I'd create a sample project outside of any existing projects to play around with the features, that way you're not fighting any kind of technology stack weirdness. One way to verify the linter is working (shown to me by a coworker) is to put in an if statement like the following:

```
var testVar = false;
if (testVar) {
  testVr = true;
}
```

You should get a warning in the if-block. Good luck!